# Deleting row from the Database and the table

Tags: php, html, mysql, delete-row

I am new to PHP so please dont go mad on me for this.
I am trying to delete rows from table but an notice is coming that :-

> Notice: Undefined variable: id in A:\PHP\htdocs\0\delete.php on line 5
>
> Record deleted successfully

But the record is not getting deleted from the table and database.

```
 <?php

 require('connect.php');

 $sql = "DELETE * FROM upload WHERE id='$id'";

 $result = mysql_query($sql); 

 if ($result) { 
 echo "Record deleted successfully";
 } else {
 echo "Error deleting record: " . mysql_error();
 }

?>
```

Comment: from where you are getting `$id` ?

Comment: if you want to delete all rows you have to use "TRUNCATE table upload" or if you want to delete specific rows then  get the $id and use "DELETE * FROM upload WHERE id=$id '"

Comment: You need to pass `$id` to your php file with GET or POST. Where is `$id`?

Comment: Should be `DELETE FROM upload WHERE id='$id'`...  `*` is used for `SELECT`statements.

Answer (score 1):

To delete a record no need to use DELETE * FROM you can use DELETE FROM.
The following query help you

```
$ids = array(3, 4);
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM tableName WHERE `id` IN (implode(',', $ids));
```

Try out this.

Comment: by using single query you have to delete multiple rows. Is my understanding correct.?

Comment: Yes. I want to do that .

Answer (score 1):

this will work for you

```
$id='3'; //any id you want to delete
$query = "DELETE FROM `upload` WHERE `id` = '$id'";
```

Comment: I don't want to delete any single row. Suppose i have 15 rows and a separate delete button for each row now i want to delete row number 5 then 8 so on so forth...

Comment: you don't want a delete the record by it's id?

Comment: Yes i do want to but if i use $id='3'; then it will allow me to delete only ROW NUMBER 3, What if i want to also delete row 4 and 5 .

Comment: $id='4'; and go on
i hope this will work for you
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_delete.asp

Comment: i have to enter manually but i dont want that. $id should pick the id automatically from DB when someone clicks the delete button

Comment: nop, you need to provide the id within the button / url where people clic, and within your php get this id to be used inside the query. It's not magic, you have to do it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Quite self explanatory, you don't have the variable $id set, this needs to be the id of the row, you should also remove the asterisk from your statement as this is not required when deleting

Answer (score -5):

To delete all row just use
Delete * from upload

Comment: I don not want to delete all .

Comment: Then u forget to set $id because that value is null